# How can I override box-ui-elements css with bootstrap css?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I'm working on a CRA project, and the [box-ui-elements](https://github.com/box/box-ui-elements) library is overriding my bootstrap styles.

When I import ContentExplorer from box-ui-elements, all my bootstrap buttons get messed up. Even when I go into devtools and put the bootstrap stylesheet last in the head element, the styles are still off.

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/box/box-ui-elements/issues/522) mentioning this problem, but I'm not sure what to make of it.

Any recommendations for using the content explorer from Box and not having it mess with my bootstrap styles?

Comment: Dare I ask why you're using two design libraries? CSS 101: Load the preferred library after the other, or write more specific override rules. There's no magic bullet if the troublesome library doesn't provide prefixed class names.

Comment: @isherwood box-ui-elements is where I'm getting the components from and bootstrap is the design library I'm using.